# How to completely serialize/deserialize RSAParameters object

Tags: .net, security, serialization

The `RSAParameters` object does not support serialization of private key data.  How can I serialize and deserialize a private key completely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code may be used to serialize and deserialize `RSAParameters` objects, using the serializer of your own choosing.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

[Serializable]
public class RSAParametersSerializable : ISerializable
{
    private RSAParameters _rsaParameters;

    public RSAParameters RSAParameters
    {
        get
        {
            return _rsaParameters;
        }
    }

    public RSAParametersSerializable(RSAParameters rsaParameters)
    {
        _rsaParameters = rsaParameters;
    }

    private RSAParametersSerializable()
    {
    }

    public byte[] D { get { return _rsaParameters.D; } set { _rsaParameters.D = value; } }

    public byte[] DP { get { return _rsaParameters.DP; } set { _rsaParameters.DP = value; } }

    public byte[] DQ { get { return _rsaParameters.DQ; } set { _rsaParameters.DQ = value; } }

    public byte[] Exponent { get { return _rsaParameters.Exponent; } set { _rsaParameters.Exponent = value; } }

    public byte[] InverseQ { get { return _rsaParameters.InverseQ; } set { _rsaParameters.InverseQ = value; } }

    public byte[] Modulus { get { return _rsaParameters.Modulus; } set { _rsaParameters.Modulus = value; } }

    public byte[] P { get { return _rsaParameters.P; } set { _rsaParameters.P = value; } }

    public byte[] Q { get { return _rsaParameters.Q; } set { _rsaParameters.Q = value; } }

    public RSAParametersSerializable(SerializationInfo information, StreamingContext context)
    {
        _rsaParameters = new RSAParameters()
        {
            D = (byte[])information.GetValue("D", typeof(byte[])),
            DP = (byte[])information.GetValue("DP", typeof(byte[])),
            DQ = (byte[])information.GetValue("DQ", typeof(byte[])),
            Exponent = (byte[])information.GetValue("Exponent", typeof(byte[])),
            InverseQ = (byte[])information.GetValue("InverseQ", typeof(byte[])),
            Modulus = (byte[])information.GetValue("Modulus", typeof(byte[])),
            P = (byte[])information.GetValue("P", typeof(byte[])),
            Q = (byte[])information.GetValue("Q", typeof(byte[]))
        };
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("D", _rsaParameters.D);
        info.AddValue("DP", _rsaParameters.DP);
        info.AddValue("DQ", _rsaParameters.DQ);
        info.AddValue("Exponent", _rsaParameters.Exponent);
        info.AddValue("InverseQ", _rsaParameters.InverseQ);
        info.AddValue("Modulus", _rsaParameters.Modulus);
        info.AddValue("P", _rsaParameters.P);
        info.AddValue("Q", _rsaParameters.Q);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XmlSerializer, example:

```
public static class RSAExtensionMethods
{
    public static XElement ToXml(this RSAParameters rsa)
    {
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, rsa);
            return XElement.Parse(writer.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static RSAParameters FromXml(XElement xml)
    {
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml.ToString()))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
            return (RSAParameters)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```