# Store a RsaSecurityKey in DB

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, rsa, identityserver4

How can I store an object of class RsaSecurityKey https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.rsasecuritykey(v=vs.110).aspx in a relational database (like Postgres)?

I have to create RsaSecurityKey (first time) and store the key in db and use it in Identity Server (using IdentityServer4 library) for signing Jwt tokens.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that you will ever be able to store objects of that type to the DB as-is, since they're not serializable - eg: if you try to use the .NET `BinaryFormatter` to turn it into a byte array it will fail with a `SerializationException`.

A bit of googling shows that there are others that have also run into this issue, eg in the AzureAD project:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/591

If you follow [the pull request](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/commit/65ceeb1c55429ccb483bb22996be1d81af12a37f) in that issue, there is source code which seems to do what you're looking for. **Note: make sure you understand the license if you intend to use it.**

Comment: As far as I understood from the links is that they ran into the issue to serialize the key as JsonWebKey and the pull request is doing that. However, then we need to store JsonWebKey into the db. right?  I think it would be better to keep the RSAParameters of the key into the database and create key when required using the parameters. But, I am not sure if this is right approach or not.

Comment: You can do it either way. Either store the serialized JsonWebKey in the database, or store the RSAParameters in the DB and rebuild your RsaSecurityKey using the parameters as needed. The source code in that pull request should be enough to help you accomplish either one of these, as it also shows what parameters you need to store.

Answer (score 2):

In IdentityServer we serialize the whole RSA key to a JSON object.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/666d76d07a790f6c1e2f35a8a90def66f7b9268c/src/IdentityServer4/Configuration/DependencyInjection/BuilderExtensions/Crypto.cs#L108-L146

You could use the same technique to store the key in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the key, you can store the parameters that create the key. 
The Original RSAParameters won't serialize correctly, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573694/how-to-completely-serialize-deserialize-rsaparameters-object) how to do make it possible. 
The example below using a file instead of db to store the parameters, but you get the idea.

```
RSAParameters param;
try{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(paramFile);
    param = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RSAParameters>(json);
}catch(Exception _)
{
    param = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048).ExportParameters(true);
    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param);
    File.WriteAllText(paramFile, jsonString);
}
var securityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(param);
```